# How assign DataSet with many Tables to CrystalViewer?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need assign a DataSet (with many Tables), to a ReportDocument and then assign it to CystalReportViewer.

But with this code I can't show the report. How can I do this??

```
protected void btnGenerarErrores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtNumeroBoleta.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        ReportDocument reporte = new ReportDocument();
        var ruta = Server.MapPath("ReporteErroresPorBoleta.rpt");
        reporte.Load(ruta);
        string parametro = txtNumeroBoleta.Text;

        clsReportesBoletaDat reportesBoleta = new clsReportesBoletaDat();
        DataSet setErrores = reportesBoleta.RetornarBoletasPorASA(parametro);

        DataSet dsNuevo = setErrores.Copy();
        reporte.SetDataSource(dsNuevo.Tables.ToString());

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;

        //if (setErrores.Tables.Count > 0)
        //{          
        //    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;               
        //}
        txtNumeroBoleta.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First clear the existing datasource connections for your report object:

```
reporte.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
```

You do not need to make a copy of your dataset you can just set the datasource to the original dataset:

```
reporte.SetDataSource(setErrores);
```

If table names in the dataset do not match table names/alias in report you may need to set them individually:

```
reporte.Tables["ReportTable"].SetDataSource(setErrores.Tables["DataSetTable"]);
```

Then set the reportsource for the viewer to your report and refresh it:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```